# How to find link for source.list?

Tags: installation

i want to install gnome evolution from git repo. I am getting errors when i run the below command: `/configure prefix=/opt`
 So i want to use apt-get build-dep command. But i am getting this error

`E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

I should add /etc/apt/sources.list uri i know, but couldn't find uri for sources.list file. How can find it?

Comment: You must have permission to write in destination directory. For /opt it's usually root, you might be better off creating a directory within /opt and adjust permissions accordingly. Also, it is `./configure --prefix=/opt` in the source directory

Comment: I know it is only simple example. What should i sources.list as repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the sources are beneath the binary packages.

```
# ubuntu precise
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

The `deb-src` line defines the source repository.